# How to do constructor injection of the feign client interface?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

Can feign client in spring boot be injected via constructor injection?

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class ApiPortImpl implements ApiPort {

    private final ApiClient feignClient;

    @Override
    public String getAuthToken() {
        return feignClient.getToken();
    }
}

interface ApiPort {

    String getAuthToken();
}

@FeignClient(name = "api-client", url = "${some_url}", path = "/", configuration = RestConfiguration.class)
interface ApiClient {

    @PostMapping(value = "/identity/token", consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    String getToken();
}

@Configuration
class RestConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    ApiPort apiPort(){
        return new ApiPortImpl(<how to do constructor injection of the feign client ??>);
    }
}
```

I do not want to use @Component annotation.
In the above mentioned code block, how can I instantiate the `ApiPortImpl` bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject ApiClient as a parameter to method annotated with @Bean:

```
@Configuration
class RestConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    ApiPort apiPort(@Autowired ApiClient apiClient){
        return new ApiPortImpl(apiClient);
    }
}
```

This should work even without @Autowired annotation.

Docs Reference: [Declaring a Bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-declaring-a-bean)

Comment: You are right. I do not even need @Autowired